# HTML image define width and height. Why distorted

Tags: html, image, height, width

I use this html-code to define width and height of the shown picture.
Why ist the image distorted in height, when I use auto. What do I wrong?

```
<img src="image01.jpg" width="80%" height="auto" alt="image01">
```

The issue is, the height is definde in the css. How can I do an exception only for this image?

```
article img {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 0.2em;
        height: 13em;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: try setting `max-width: 100%` and `object-fit: contain` on image.

Comment: I tried this, but it does't work. With this setting, ther height is 13em (cause of the css) and the width is like I use "auto"